# Count each days of week between two dates without loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can do it with loop, but if many day is slow. So I need do without loop.
Here is my code:

```
     DECLARE
         @FRDT date = '01-SEP-2019'
        ,@TODT date = '30-SEP-2019'
        ,@N int

        ,@SUN int = 0
        ,@MON int = 0
        ,@TUE int = 0
        ,@WED int = 0
        ,@THU int = 0
        ,@FRI int = 0
        ,@SAT int = 0

    WHILE @FRDT <= @TODT
    BEGIN
        SET @N = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @FRDT)
        IF @N = 1
            SET @SUN = @SUN + 1
        ELSE IF @N = 2
            SET @MON = @MON + 1
        ELSE IF @N = 3
            SET @TUE = @TUE + 1
        ELSE IF @N = 4
            SET @WED = @WED + 1
        ELSE IF @N = 5
            SET @THU = @THU + 1
        ELSE IF @N = 6
            SET @FRI = @FRI + 1
        ELSE IF @N = 7
            SET @SAT = @SAT + 1

        SET @FRDT = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FRDT)
    END

    SELECT 1 AS [NO], 'Sunday' AS [DAYNAME], @SUN AS [NUMBEROFDAY]
    UNION SELECT 2, 'Monday', @MON
    UNION SELECT 3, 'Tuesday', @TUE
    UNION SELECT 4, 'Wednesday', @WED
    UNION SELECT 5, 'Thursday', @THU
    UNION SELECT 6, 'Friday', @FRI
```

[image]

I want to result like code above, but not use loop for better performance.

Comment: If you're going to do this sort of querying frequently, you might consider creating a calendar table. With one row per day, 20 years worth of rows is less than 10000 rows, which is minuscule. You can then range query it and if one of your columns is `DayOfWeek` this becomes a trivial `GROUP BY` query against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date range is 30 days, dividing by 7 gives quotient 4 and remainder 2.

So every day of the week gets 4 and two days need an additional one. These are the ones corresponding to `@start_date` and the following day in this case.

SQL to implement this approach is below ([demo](https://rextester.com/JKXXM95309))

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,base_date),
       quotient + IIF(Nums.N < remainder, 1, 0)
FROM (VALUES 
         (0),
         (1),
         (2),
         (3),
         (4),
         (5),
         (6)) Nums(N)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT 1 + DATEDIFF(DAY,@start_date,@end_date)) DC(day_count)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, Nums.N, @start_date), day_count/7, day_count% 7) D(base_date, quotient, remainder)
ORDER BY DATEPART(DW,base_date)
```

Comment: Perfect! range date 3000 years just in millisecond. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Martin.Terrific solution.I am not able to figure out how I will implement this in calendar table without variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with using recursive CTE as below-

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE= '01-SEP-2019', @end_date DATE= '30-SEP-2019';

WITH cte
AS (
            SELECT @start_date AS date_

            UNION ALL

            SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, date_) AS DATE)
            FROM cte
            WHERE date_ < @end_date
)

SELECT  DATEPART(DW,date_) No,
DATENAME(DW,date_) Day_Name,
COUNT(*) Num_Day
FROM cte 
GROUP BY DATEPART(DW,date_),DATENAME(DW,date_)
ORDER BY DATEPART(DW,date_)
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Output-

```
No  Day_Name    Num_Day
1   Sunday      5
2   Monday      5
3   Tuesday     4
4   Wednesday   4
5   Thursday    4
6   Friday      4
7   Saturday    4
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient way

Comment: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: Did you removed the line - OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);? I have run it for 1 year data with no issue.

Comment: the recursive CTE is still a loop just hidden. It should be possible to do with simple maths. Date range is 30 days, divide by 7 gives 4 and remainder 2. So every day of the week gets 4 and as remainder is 2 then two days need an additional one. These are the ones corresponding to start_date and start_date+1

Comment: Nice one. But required union all and other string operations to get days on rows.

Comment: No string operations needed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57923340/73226 (unless you are complaining about `DATENAME` - but that is also in this answer)

Comment: I have generated 50 years data with your and mine script. Both return results by almost 0 second. So both solution is acceptable regarding inefficiency I think. Just the implementation way is difference. +1 for your script from me as I learned something new from your code :) @MartinSmith

Comment: With `set statistics time on;`  and date range of 50 years I see elapsed time = 0 ms. for my method vs elapsed time = 162 ms for recursive CTE

Comment: Hands up @MartinSmith, your one is better one obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

For such situation you need to have a `Number` table or `Date` Table.

In my example I am using a `Number` table. You can create number table anyway you want and it will help in many situations.

```
Create Table tblNumber(Number int primary key)
insert into tblNumber (Number) values(1),(2)...... till thousands or millions
```

> Edit: You could generate the numbers for this number table using:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tblNumber
> SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [N]
> FROM dbo.syscolumns tb1,dbo.syscolumns tb2
> ```
>
> Keep this table permanently as it is useful.

```
DECLARE @FromDT DATETIME= '2019-09-01';
DECLARE @ToDT DATETIME= '2019-09-30';


SELECT COUNT(*), wkday
FROM
(
  SELECT DATEname(weekday, DATEADD(day, number, @FromDT)) wkday
  FROM tblNumber
  WHERE number BETWEEN DATEPART(day, @FromDT) AND DATEPART(day, @ToDT)
) tbl
GROUP BY wkday;
```

If you have a `Date` table then it is more efficient in this situation.

Comment: @Sophairk , how come you say that `It's the same to loop. slow performance`.In no way you can compare this with loop and in no way without Testing you can say that its `slow performance`.I tested with Calendar table date 10000000 rows.It executed in millisecond.